# ASP.NET WebApi и связаны ресурсы

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация, asp.net-web-api

Доброго времени суток.

Нужна ваша помощь. Есть ASP.NET WebApi приложение в котором нужно представить связь двух ресурсов. 
Например есть сущность `StreetType` которая возвращает json:

```
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"StreetType1",
}
```

и сущность `Street`:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Street1",
  "streettypeid":3
}
```

Ранее для получения связанных ресурсов использовал OData запрос: `http://localhost:3761/api/Street?$expand=StreetType`

Но, так как в некоторых сущностей может быть 3 и более связанных ресурсы то писать такие запросы будет сложно ну и не очень красиво.

Было бы неплохо реализовать это следующим образом:

1. `http://localhost:3761/api/Street/` - все `Street`
2. `http://localhost:3761/api/full/Street/` - все `Street` и связанные ресурсы (в этом случае только StreetType)
3. `http://localhost:3761/api/Street/1` - `Street` с `ID = 1`
4. `http://localhost:3761/api/full/Street/1` - `Street` с `ID = 1` и связанные ресурсы

Но есть проблема с системой маршрутизации и наследованием атрибутов. Так как все это должно быть реализовано в базовом классе.

Вопрос: Как правильно реализовать представление связанных объектов?
Как оформить простой URL например для такого запроса OData: `http://localhost:3761/api/City?$expand=CityType,Region`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть небольшая книга по проектированию API интерфейсов автора Brian Mulloy, называется Web API Design Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love.
В ней приводятся примеры, как вашу проблему решали крупные корпорации, в частности

```
Facebook: /joe.smith/friends?fields=id,name,picture
Google:  ?fields=title,media:group(media:thumbnail)
LinkedIn: /people:(id,first-name,last-name,industry)
```

Можно так же разделять поля сущности на обязательные и дополнительные, где обязательные выгружать всегда, а дополнительные по запросу.

В целом, запрос http://localhost:3761/api/City?$expand=CityType,Region выглядит неправильно, т.к. вы сцепляете разные сущности. Логичнее получать Region отдельным запросом.